# Switch - default not working in C

Tags: c, switch-statement, default

I'm new around here and I'm also new to C language. I do have a problem with my switch despite having a default. I have a menu with options from 1 to 5 and also 0. The thing is that when I run the program and introduce any number with more than 1 digit, the program only reads the first digit and executes the corresponding option.
For example, if I introduce 13, program will open option number 1, if I introduce 243, the program will open the second option and so on. The same happens if I introduce a combination of numbers and letters, like 1d, 4b, 5A etc.

Can you help me please?

```
int main()  
{
  char opcao, terminar=1; /*Zona de declaraÃ§Ã£o das variÃ¡veis*/
  MODULO mlunar;
  MODULO *maux=NULL;
  PONTOS *ponto=NULL, *p1=NULL;

  do
  {         
    printf("\n1 - Especificação dos dados do módulo e das condições iniciais do voo  \n");
    printf("2 - Simulalção do voo em modo de cockpit \n");
    printf("3 - Apresentação em modo gráfico da trajectória do módulo \n");
    printf("4 - Definição do perfil da superfície lunar \n");                      /*Imprime as opÃ§Ãµes no ecrÃ£*/
    printf("5 - Simulação do voo em modo gráfico \n");
    printf("0 - Terminar o programa \n");
    printf("\nEscolha uma das opções acima indicadas, carregando no respetivo numero: ");

    opcao=getchar(); /*Leitura da opção seleccionada*/      
    while(getchar()!='\n'){}; /*Limpar o buffer do teclado*/

    switch(opcao)  /*Condição para cada opção selecionada*/   
    {
      case '1': /*Caso o utilizador carregue em '1', é invocada a função da 1ª opção e assim sucessivamente.*/
        maux=opcao1(&mlunar); break; 
      case '2':
        if(maux!=NULL)
        {
          opcao2(&mlunar); 
        }
        else
        {
          printf("\n\nOpção 1 NÃO EXECUTADA! Por favor, execute a primeira opção.\n");break;
        }
      case '3': 
        opcao3(mlunar); break;
      case '4': 
        p1=opcao4(ponto); break;
      case '5': 
        opcao5(p1); break;
      case '0':
        printf("\nDeseja terminar o programa? \n S/s - sim \n N/n - não \n");
        terminar=getchar(); /*Leitura da opção seleccionada*/       
        while(getchar()!='\n'){}; /*Limpar o buffer do teclado*/
        while (terminar!='s' && terminar!='S' && terminar!='n' && terminar!='N') /*O utilizador não inseriu nenhuma das opções apresentadas*/
        {
          printf("\nA opção selecionada é inválida! Por favor, introduza uma opção válida.\n");
          terminar=getchar();       
          while (getchar()!='\n'){}
        }
      default:
        printf("\nA opção selecionada não existe! Por favor, introduza uma opção que conste na lista.\n");
    }
  } 
  while(terminar!= 's' && terminar!= 'S'); /*Enquanto a variavel 'terminar' nao receber um S ou s, o prorama nao terminara*/
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, as in the first look, your `case '2'` and `case '0'` are missing `break;`. Also, you need to check the usage logic for `getchar()`.

Comment: Your problem is `getchar()` it only reads one character which is `1` in case of `13` and `2` in case of `243`. Therefore, it enters in `case '1':` and `case '2':` not `default:`.

Comment: Try [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/) (beta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare `opcao` as an `int` and use

```
scanf("%d",&opcao);
```

instead of

```
opcao=getchar();
```

and the `switch-case` will look like

```
switch(opcao)
{
case 1://code
  break;
case 2://code
  break;
case 3://code
  break;
case 4://code
  break;
case 5://code
  break;
case 0://code
  break;
default://code
}
```

There is no way that you can detect if the user entered more than a character by scanning a character.You'll have to use an `int`.Since all your `case`s consist of numbers,you're in luck.

Comment: Why are you suggesting to use `int`?

Comment: I tried your way but now it doesn't accept any characters at all, even options. It gives me back a print that I established inside the default.

Comment: @Gopi , Why use `char` data type when we are dealing with numbers?

Comment: @Nikita ,Did you change `case '1'` to `case 1` ? Similarly for all the other cases

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing for character codes, not numbers. `getchar` reads exactly one character. If you enter a number it will read exactly one digit (in form as a character) so no matter how long the number is, only the first digits will make it into the switch statement. You need to fix that.

How to do: Replace `getchar` with some function that reads and parses a number. in the switch statement, don't compare for character codes, but numbers.